# Disambiguating a function pointer

Tags: c++, stl

To choose between two comparison functions, I can write the following code:

```
const float& (*cmp)(const float&, const float&);
if (cmp_type >= 0)
    cmp = &std::max;
else
    cmp = &std::min;
```

I would like to combine it to a single line using the ?: expression:

```
const float& (*cmp)(const float&, const float&)(cmp_type >= 0 ? &std::max : &std::min);
```

But unfortunately, in this case as oppose to:

```
const float& (*cmp)(const float&, const float&)(&std::max);
```

The two definitions of std::max collide inside the ?: expression:

```
template<typename _Tp> inline const _Tp& max(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b);
template<typename _Tp> inline _Tp max(initializer_list<_Tp> __l);
```

Causing a compilation error.

What are my choices for making the ?: expression work?

Comment: It looks like you'll need to use initialization assignment: `const float& (*cmp)(const float&, const float&) = (cmp_type >= 0 ? &std::max : &std::min);`

Comment: @owacoder: That wouldn't help. `&std::max` is still tyring to take the address of an overloaded function, and such an expression can only be used in a context where overload resolution happens. The subexpressions in `?:` are not such a context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a `typedef` and use it to `static_cast` to get the correct overload.

```
using cmp_t = const float&(*)(const float&, const float&); // typedef

cmp_t cmp = cmp_type>=0 ? static_cast<cmp_t>(std::max) :
                          static_cast<cmp_t>(std::min);
```